# How to pass an input target value and setState values as parameters for a helper function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a function that looks like this, it takes an input file and posts it to the backend:

```
const loadFile = async ({ target }) => {
    const file = target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const { name, size } = file;

      // TODO: CHANGE URL
      if (size > 5000000) {
        setIsUploadError('File size too big');
      } else {
        const res = await PostData(`${BACKEND_ADDRESS}/${UPLOAD_ENDPOINT}`, file, userId, isUploading, uploadError);
        if (res) {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            const resJson = await res.json();

            const newUpload = {
              id: resJson.id,
              upload: {
                id: resJson.upload_id,
                title: name,
                url: resJson.url,
              },
            };
            setIsUploadLoading(false);
          } else if (res.status === 500) {
            setIsUploadError('Error uploading');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="buttonUpload"
  onChange={loadFile}
/>
```

Tried to move it to a helper function file, add the postData() function it uses also there and then import it and call it something like this:

```
loadFile(userId, target, setIsUploadError);
```

Can't get it to work:

```
Error: target is not defined
```

How to get the target file passed as parameter from the input? Is it ok to pass the hooks setState values (setIsUploadError) just like that?

Comment: `loadFile` is expecting an object containing `target` as property inside it. You need to call it as `loadFile({userId, target, setIsUploadError})`

Comment: Use the approach from @theincrediblethor  . there you can pass event and what ever the parameters like state etc.,

Comment: Getting still an ```Error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined``` The helper function starts now like this ```export const LoadFile = async ({ userId, target, uploadError }) => {..``` and now trying to call it from the input: ```onChange={e => LoadFile(userId, e.target, setIsUploadError)}```

Comment: @Tushar This gives also a parsing error on e.target: ```onChange={e => LoadFile({ userId, e.target, setIsUploadError })}```

Comment: `onChange={e => LoadFile({ userId, target: e.target, setIsUploadError })}`

Comment: Thank you guys and specially @Tushar now the file is passes. Updated the answer regarding the problem that remains with the error on setState variables. Any ideas on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="buttonUpload"
    onChange={(e)=> loadFile(e.target)}
/>
```

Capture the click event in the onChange function and pass the target to the callback function